# Creating Hyperlink by Concatenating Link Template with Text in Cells - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, concatenation

I am trying to turn a column that has text in it into a hyperlink. The columns will have information which I want to add at the end of the link template. For example, let's say:

```
 "/stackoverflow.com/" is my link template
 Range("A2") = "a_two" and Range("A3") = "a_three"
```

I want to convert cell A2 and A3 into hyperlinks and set the URLs to 
     "/stackoverflow.com/a_two" and 
     "/stackoverflow.com/a_three" respectively. How can I do this?

Thanks all

Answer (score -2):

```
      Dim r as range
      For each r in selection
          activesheet.hyperlinks.add Anchor:=r,Address:="/stackoverflow.com/" & r.text
      next r
```

Comment: well that was an unpopular answer. Anyone want to explain why they're down voting?